# MongoDB $regex query for “end with” "$" char

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to filter keys that end with $ character. 
For example, I have the following dict:

```
"list" : [
        {
            "username" : "user1",
            "exist" : "true"
        },
        {
            "username" : "user$",
            "exist" : "true"
        },
        {
            "username" : "user3",
            "exist" : "false"
        }
]
```

now, I want to filter the user that ends with `$` :

```
db.collection('users').find({username: {"$regex": /$$/, $options: 'i'}})
```

But it's not working for me probably because the `$` sign used for defending the end of a string. I've tried to use `/^/$/$/` and some others but with no luck.

Could you please assist ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not just with **MongoDB**, by default regex doesn't work like that. Also you might not need to use `$regex` operator.

**Query 1:** If you want to match words which contain `$`.

```
db.collection.find({username: /[$]/})
```

**Output:** `use$r, user$ , $user`

**Query 2:** If you want to match words which contain `$` at the end.

```
db.collection.find({username: /[$]$/})
```

**Output:** `user$`